# after bind MapDispatchtoProps Can't use this.props

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

i try to figure out what's wrong in my code. can someone help me find out whats wrong. i use webstorm for text editing, and it's show "unresolve variable" in

> this.**props**.loginUser(value);

is there any related to this?

this is my code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {reduxForm,  Field} from 'redux-form';
import { loginUser } from '../actions/index';
import { Stores }   from '../Stores';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const validate = values => {
    const errors = {};
    if (!values.email) {
        errors.email = 'Required'
    } else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)) {
        errors.email = 'Invalid email address'
    }
    if (!values.password) {
        errors.password = 'Required'
    }
    return errors
};

const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
    <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <div>
            <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} className="form-control"/>
            {touched && error && <span className="alert alert-danger">{error}</span>}
        </div>
    </div>
);

function submit(value){
    console.log(value);
    this.props.loginUser(value); //didn't work
    // Stores.dispatch(loginUser({email,password})); //this method work
}

class LoginV6 extends Component{

    render() {
        const {handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting} = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6">

                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <Field
                                name="email"
                                type="text"
                                component={renderField}
                                label="Email"
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <Field
                                name="password"
                                type="password"
                                component={renderField}
                                label="Password"
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" disabled={pristine||submitting}>
                                Login
                            </button>

                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" disabled={pristine || submitting}
                                    onClick={reset}>
                                Clear Values
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
     return {
         loginUser() {
             dispatch({loginUser(value));
         }
     }
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        errorMessage: state.auth.error,
        authenticated:state.auth.authenticated
    }
}

LoginV6 =  reduxForm({
    form:'LoginV6',
    validate
})(LoginV6);

export default LoginV6 = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginV6);
```

this is my action code :

```
import axios from 'axios';
import jwtdecode from 'jwt-decode';
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import {
    AUTH_USER,
    AUTH_ERROR,
    USER_INFO_SUCCESS,
    USER_INFO,
    LOGOUT_USER,
    GET_TABPANEL,
    GET_SETUP_TABTITLES,
} from './types';

const ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:8000';

// User and Auth actions
// 
export function loginUser({email,password}){
    return function(dispatch){
        axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/api/auth/login`,{email,password})
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({type: AUTH_USER,
                    payload:response.data.token
                });
                localStorage.setItem('laravel_user_token',response.data.token);
                console.log('Login Success');
                browserHistory.push("/");
            }).catch(()=>{
            dispatch(authError("Empty Required Field"));
        });
    }
}
```

if i use **Stores.dispatch(loginUser(value));** it works.

Comment: what error do you see in console

Comment: @Aatif Bandey : nothing happen.

Comment: do you defined prop `loginUser` in parent component?

Comment: @Aatif Bandey : class LoginV6 is the parent component.

Comment: I have not used `redux` i am have used `flux` but i think you are not defining prop `loginUser` which is creating an issue for you

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
class LoginV6 extends Component{
    constructor(){
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this); //Because ES6 is not auto bind
    }
    submit(value){
        //...your code
        this.props.loginUser(value); //it will work
        // or "loginUser" is an action
        this.props.dispatch(loginUser(value)); //see the new function mapDispatchToProps
    }
    render(){
        //...your code 
    }
}
// ....
// instead map a new object, we map dispatch directly 
// with this function, we avoid duplicated/confused about actions in case you have many actions
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        dispatch
    }
};
```

Comment: got error. i change the constructor to this one : `constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this); //Because ES6 is not auto bind
    }` but i got another error on <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>, it's say on console : "LoginV6.js:54 Uncaught ReferenceError: submit is not defined"

Comment: You can try "onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit)}" . Because function submit is belong to class LoginV6 now. Also, your code have a bit complicated, "handleSubmit" and "loginUser" is actions. The "handleSubmit" should be write inside class LoginV6, and it's same meaning with function "submit"

Comment: @ Nguyễn Nhân : i already try it. and it's work. thx you so much.

Answer (score 0):

i already fix this by change my code to this :

```
class LoginV6 extends Component{

    submit = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.props.loginUser(data);
    }

    render() {
        const {handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting} = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6">

                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit)}>

..............................the rest of code..............................................

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
            loginUser: (data) => {
                dispatch(loginUser(data))
            }
        }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            errorMessage: state.auth.error,
            authenticated:state.auth.authenticated
        }
    }

    LoginV6 =  reduxForm({
        form:'LoginV6',
        validate
    })(LoginV6);

    export default LoginV6 = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginV6);
```